# Why would getSettings return null on a webview?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a tiny percentage of my users for whom I am getting a null value when I call `getSettings()` so I can set some values.

This is what my code looks like on my latest version and I've already had one non-fatal exception report on Crashlytics:

```
 WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        if (settings == null) {
            sendExceptionThroughCrashlytics(new NullPointerException("Web settings is null"));
        }else{ .....}
```

So what could be causing this? I know it is a tiny percentage of my users this is affecting but I would still prefer to fix the issue.  Every device so far has been a Samsung, all at or below 4.3.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to check this line from Official Doc [WebSetting](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) `If a WebView has been destroyed, any method call on WebSettings will throw an IllegalStateException.`

Comment: I am not getting that, I am getting a null on the call `webView.getSettings()`. Also I am only doing this when the webview is first created and all my methods to get rid of that webview run on the same thread so they can't get called until this is done.